# How to extract JSON parameter using JsonSlurper in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

I've written the following groovy script in SOAPUI to execute an assertion on a JSON response.

I'm having difficulty writing the assertion to extract and assert on Weather > main > Clouds property and value of the JSON response.

Can someone please assist with correcting my code to extract the value I want?

Thanks!

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
"coord": {
  "lon": -0.13,
  "lat": 51.51
  },
 "weather": [
  {
     "id": 801,
     "main": "Clouds",
     "description": "few clouds",
     "icon": "02n"
  }
  ],
 "base": "stations",
  "main": {
  "temp": 281.644,
  "pressure": 1027.43,
  "humidity": 100,
  "temp_min": 281.644,
  "temp_max": 281.644,
  "sea_level": 1035.14,
  "grnd_level": 1027.43
   },
  "wind": {
  "speed": 3.33,
  "deg": 43.5005
 },
 "clouds": {
  "all": 12
 },
 "dt": 1476231232,
  "sys": {
  "message": 0.0084,
  "country": "GB",
  "sunrise": 1476253200,
  "sunset": 1476292372
},
  "id": 2643743,
 "name": "London",
 "cod": 200
   }'''


def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
log.info(result)
assert result.weather.main == "Clouds"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weather is an array of maps, as I see. So, you need to select an item or groovy will return to you an array of main.

```
assert result.weather.first().main == "Clouds"
​assert result.weather.main == ["Clouds"​]​
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks it's a trivial issue.

`weather` is an array(in []) and that is why the assertion fails.

```
"weather": [
  {
     "id": 801,
     "main": "Clouds",
     "description": "few clouds",
     "icon": "02n"
  }
  ],
```

If you do `result.weather​.main​`, then it returns a list which contains an element `Clouds`. But,not a single value as you expected.

So, you can do:

`assert result.weather​[0].main == 'Clouds', 'Not matching the expected result'` or
`assert result.weather​.main == ['Clouds']` or
`assert result.weather.main.contains('Clouds')`

For suppose if weather is below (example with more elements in json array):

```
"weather": [
  {
     "id": 801,
     "main": "Clouds",
     "description": "few clouds",
     "icon": "02n"
  },
  {
     "id": 802,
     "main": "CloudApps",
     "description": "few clouds",
     "icon": "03n"
  }
  ],
```

Then assertion can be done
`assert result.weather.main == ['Clouds', 'CloudApps']`

Answer (score 0):

weather in your json is array. You can access it elements as a regular array

```
assert result.weather.main[0] == "Clouds"
assert result?.weather?.main?.getAt(0) == "Clouds"
```

second prefered because it null safe